# Where can I find the details of the Legion of Folded Paper Feat?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, feats, content-identification, character-templates

I've been tooling around with a *Pathfinder 1E* campaign of mine, specifically with trying out some templates for potential monster encounters. While I was doing this, I stumbled across the [Ofuda](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/ofuda-cr-1/) template. It puts some interesting restrictions on the creatures in question, but what caught my eye was the bonus casters get for summoning Ofuda-ized creatures over the standard types. You get to summon additional creatures than the spell normally would, 1d3 instead of a single, 1d4 instead of 1d3 and I assume 1d6+1 instead of 1d4+1. However, it mentions a feat by the name of *Legion of Folded Paper* that would increase the number of bonus creatures you'd get from a single cast. The problem is I can't find this feat anywhere online let alone the specifics for how it works.

**Does anyone know where I can find these rules? Does anyone know how this feat functions?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feat is from Green Ronin's [Advanced Bestiary](https://greenroninstore.com/products/advanced-bestiary-for-the-pathfinder-roleplaying-game-pdf), which is also where the template is from.

> **Prerequisites:** Ability to cast summon monster or summon nature’s ally as a spell or spell-like ability.
>
> **Benefit:** Whenever you cast summon monster or summon nature’s ally as a spell or spell-like ability, you may choose to call 1d4+1 ofuda creatures of the spell’s level rather than 1d3. In addition, you gain +1 ofuda creatures of the appropriate type for every level higher the spell-effect is than the summon table where reselected creature appears. For example, with a summon monster IV spell, a caster can summon 1d4+1 ofuda giant scorpions, 1d4+2 ofuda cheetahs (from the summon monster III table), 1d4+3 ofuda giant centipedes (from the summon monster II table), or 1d4+4 ofuda dire rats (from the summon monster I table).
>
> This cannot be applied to summoning due to the summon universal monster ability.

---

As for how summoning Ofuda creatures works, if you were to say cast Summon Monster 6, you could summon 1d3 Ofuda creatures from the Summon Monster 6 list, or 1d4+1 Ofuda creatures from the any list below that (going two lists or more lower is still only 1d4+1 monsters, the legion of folded paper feat changes that).